# Tumblr Theme photos - how to stop linking to larger image and link to permalink

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

Hi there :  I have a simple theme with what I thought was a simple issue.   In the photo block - I want to have the image when clicked to go to the "permalink" page for that post, not expand the image into a light box or show the image.   There is no obvious HREF to modify to go to permalink - so I'm lost.

From the permalink page - Expanding is fine.   I've tinkered with all of the variables and I can completely turn off the linking of images - but cannot modify behavior to send them to the permalink.   Hope this makes sense - and thanks in advance.

Full code is also here:  [fullcode from theme](http://www.bestofmoderndesign.com/tumblr-code/)

the actual tumblr is: [bestofmoderndesign.tumblr.com](http://bestofmoderndesign.tumblr.com)

code :

```
 {block:Photo}
                            <div class="media">
                                {LinkOpenTag}
                                    <img src="{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoURL-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:IfNot500pxPosts}{PhotoURL-400}{/block:IfNot500pxPosts}{block:If500pxPosts}{PhotoURL-500}{/block:If500pxPosts}{/block:IndexPage}" width="{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoWidth-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:IfNot500pxPosts}{/block:IfNot500pxPosts}{block:If500pxPosts}{PhotoWidth-500}{/block:If500pxPosts}{/block:IndexPage}" height="{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoHeight-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:IfNot500pxPosts}{PhotoHeight-400}{/block:IfNot500pxPosts}{block:If500pxPosts}{PhotoHeight-500}{/block:If500pxPosts}{/block:IndexPage}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
                                {LinkCloseTag}
                                {block:IfEnableColorbox}
                                    <a href='{PhotoURL-HighRes}' class='fullsize colorbox' rel="fullsize"><span>{lang:Click for high-res photo}</span></a>
                                {/block:IfEnableColorbox}
                            </div>
                            {block:Caption}
                                <div class="copy">{Caption}</div>
                            {/block:Caption}
                        {/block:Photo}
```

Comment: Usually I would think you would change the href so `<a href='{PhotoURL-HighRes}' ` should become `<a href='{Permalink}'` (off the top of my head). But your theme has a custom lightbox from what I can tell. So I think you will either need to post a link to your blog and/or the entire code.

Comment: Thanks!  I just updated the question with a link to the full code as well as a link to the tumblr itself.   -  Also I agree on the href.   But that's when the custom lightbox is used (which is something called colorbox which I have disabled -- so that if statement for the href isn't being triggered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{LinkOpenTag}` and `{LinkCloseTag}` are what are generating the link to the large image page. 

Instead use `<a href='{Permalink}'>` and `</a>`.

If you want it to continue this behaviour on permalink pages you can always change the code to something like:

```
{block:Photo}
    <div class="media">
        {block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}
        {block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}">{/block:IndexPage}
            <img src="{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoURL-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:IfNot500pxPosts}{PhotoURL-400}{/block:IfNot500pxPosts}{block:If500pxPosts}{PhotoURL-500}{/block:If500pxPosts}{/block:IndexPage}" width="{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoWidth-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:IfNot500pxPosts}{/block:IfNot500pxPosts}{block:If500pxPosts}{PhotoWidth-500}{/block:If500pxPosts}{/block:IndexPage}" height="{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoHeight-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:IfNot500pxPosts}{PhotoHeight-400}{/block:IfNot500pxPosts}{block:If500pxPosts}{PhotoHeight-500}{/block:If500pxPosts}{/block:IndexPage}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
        {block:IndexPage}</a>{/block:IndexPage}
        {block:PermalinkPage}{LinkCloseTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}
        {block:IfEnableColorbox}
            <a href='{PhotoURL-HighRes}' class='fullsize colorbox' rel="fullsize"><span>{lang:Click for high-res photo}</span></a>
        {/block:IfEnableColorbox}
    </div>
    {block:Caption}
        <div class="copy">{Caption}</div>
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photo}
```

Comment: Ahhhh!  yes - that does technically work - but it breaks all of the other variables  i.e.  the custom link given to the image when posting.  And for some reason it also prohibits the image zoom on the permalinked page.  Make sense?      =\

Comment: Well that's the only way to get rid of it. You can always just put the link open and close tags on the permalink pages and the permalink link on the index page

Comment: Thank Chloe - I appreciate it.  Didn't think of that.

Comment: @Phil mind accepting my answer? I updated it to include the code to make the image zoom happen on permalink pages only.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the code. Since you don't want it to link to hi-res image, I've completely removed it so it automatically links directly to the permalink page
{block:Photo}

```
    <div class="media">
        {block:IndexPage}
            {block:IfNot500pxPosts}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-400}"></a>{/block:IfNot500pxPosts}
            {block:If500pxPosts}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}"></a>{/block:If500pxPosts}
        {/block:IndexPage}

        {block:PermalinkPage}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}">{/block:PermalinkPage}
    </div>
    {block:Caption}
        <div class="copy">{Caption}</div>
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photo}
```